# Accessing a web page's source rather than DOM for my Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and need to access information that seems only to exist in the webpage's source (i.e: seen under "**view Page Source**"), but not the DOM (seen in chrome's "**Inspect**" tool). In Python I can easily scrape the page and find what I'm looking for, but not so in JavaScript.

The information in question is in the "js-store" class of the Page Source:

```
</head>
<body style="background-color: #111; margin: 0" >
            
                

            <div class="js-page js-global-wrapper">
                    </div>
        <div class="js-cmp"></div>
                                <div class="js-store" data-content="{&quot;config..."></div>
```

When viewed with the Inspector, the js-store class does not exist.

Thanks for your help!

*Note: this is my first JavaScript project so I apologize if there is an obvious answer*

**Edit**:  I can load the data if I turn off JavaScript with the Google Inspector. Also, I have specified in the manifest to run the script at "document_start" but still no success there

Comment: There's no such API so try running the content script at [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time) and use MutationObserver with a simple document.querySelector check inside its callback.

Comment: Is there a way to store the initial state of the DOM? When I run my code with the 'document_start' setting enabled, I still cannot access the data I need. So far the only workaround method is to disable javascript and then re-enable it

Comment: There's no such way. Did you use MutationObserver?